# Characters are printed instead of listing dir

Tags: python-2.7, dir

I'm trying to list the files in my directory. The directory is /home/user/Desktop/Test/
Within Test, there are 3 folders, a,b,c
and within each of the folders a,b,c there are 10 gz files numbered in order 1-10

```
import os
subdir=os.walk("/home/user/Desktop/Test")
for i in subdir:
    for dir in i:
        print dir
```

I get an output of

```
a
b
c
```

I want to get

```
1.gz
2.gz
3.gz
4.gz
5.gz
6.gz
7.gz
8.gz
9.gz
10.gz
```

Where was i wrong?

Comment: Did you mean that the `a`, `b` and `c` files are actually folders?

Comment: yes. they are folders

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs. By typing help(os.walk), you will find this example:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum([getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files]),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

So if you want to list all the files in your folder, do:

```
import os

relative_dirnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
path = '/home/user/Desktop/Test'
dirs_to_list = [os.path.join(path, s) for s in relative_dirnames]

for d in dirs_to_list:
    for _, __, files in os.walk(d):
        print 'Folder: {}'.format(d)
        for f in files:
            print f
        break
```